# Use custom metrics(ex: ndcg@n) in Sagemaker(AWS) HyperparameterTuner

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use `ndcg@n` for a hyper parameter tuning job using HyperparameterTuner, I can use it as `eval_metric` in a stand-alone training job and I see it in the logs, but when trying to use it for hyper-param tuning, I face the following issues which prevent me from running my hyper-param tuning job with as optimization objective:

1. If I just set it as

`objective_metric_name="ndcg@5"`

I get

> The objective metric for the hyperparameter tuning job, [ndcg@5],
> isn’t valid for[xgboost]the algorithm. Choose a valid objective metric.

2. If I try to add it in `metrics_definition` using

`metric_definitions = [{'Name': 'validation:ndcg@5','Regex': 'ndcg@5:(\S+)'}]`

I get:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateHyperParameterTuningJob operation: You can't override the metric definitions for Amazon SageMaker algorithms. Please retry the request without specifying metric definitions.

3. If I create a custom metric(which I can see in the logs) I get the same 2 errors previously described: If I add it in metrics definitions it says I should remove them, if I remove them it says it's not valid.

It seems to me it's a major drawback not being able to use custom metrics in `HyperparameterTuner`, considering not even common metrics as precision and recall are available  I guess there should be a way to use custom-defined objective metrics  in `HyperparameterTuner`, but none of my attempts has worked. Question is: how to add custom metrics to HyperparameterTuner in Sagemaker?

**UPDATE**: actually it's not only HyperparameterTuner, I cannot even find how to add custom metrics to a simple(non HyperparameterTuner) training job, I cannot even use common metrics as precision and recall .

Comment: What version of sagemaker?

Comment: sorry @MadisonCourto, since I'm new to sagemaker, I don't know how to find the version, could you please guide me on how to see the version?